# How to make a tolltip appear only when hovering over text?

Tags: html, hover, tooltip

I have to work with HTML files where the following tooltip is extensively used:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  Text
  <span class="popup">
  Tooltip
  </span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tooltip span[class="popup"] {
                z-index:10;display:none; padding:7px 10px;
                }
.tooltip:hover span[class="popup"]{
                display:inline; position:absolute; color:#111;
                border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;
          }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f1tztx15/2/

My problem is that the tooltip not only appears when I hover over "Text" but also when I hover over the blank space at the right of "Text" (see below).

[Tooltip appearing when blank space is hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiaQB.png)

Is there a way to limit the "hoverable" region to the text without changing the whole tooltip? (I don't really have the freedom to do that)

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `<span>` around the text - currently, the container for the text is a div, which is a block element, which means that as long as you're inside the div, you'll trigger the tooltip. And I must say, that is one of the worst ways of creating a tooltip I've EVER seen.

Comment: They are learning... instead of "that is one of the worst ways of creating a tooltip I've EVER seen" how about offering a suggestion to improve it...

Comment: Oh wow, that was quick. It works great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CSS to limit the width or padding of the element.

Eg.

`.tooltip:
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0px;`

This could limit the width of your tooltip element.

You could also just use a `<span>` element. Which would also contain the element within its own bounds.

Comment: As the content of the element may vary grealty, I cannot set a fixed width. Using a <span> element works fine, thanks!

Comment: Glad some of it helped :)